# Partial 5-card poker hand evaluation

Tags: combinatorics

I have a partial 5-card poker hand. Note that order is important and the blanks may be anywhere. (So, for example, I could have `10H <blank> <blank> KH <blank>`)

I also know what cards are remaining (i.e. some subset of the (standard 52-card) deck, minus whatever cards are in the partial hand). (There are always enough cards remaining to fill out the hand)

I want to get the counts of each possible outcome (high card, one pair, two pair, ... etc) if the blanks are filled with cards randomly.

The naive algorithm (loop over all possible ways to fill the blank spaces from the cards remaining, incrementing the count of whatever that filled hand works out to be) works, but is far too slow (worst case is `52! / (52-5)! ~= 312 million` cases).

If every case was independent, it'd be "easy". Unfortunately, they aren't, and the outcome system goes somewhat like this:

```
if (hasFlush) {
    if (hasRoyal)
        return PokerHand.ROYAL_FLUSH;
    if (hasStraight)
        return PokerHand.STRAIGHT_FLUSH;
}
if (maxOfAKind == 4)
    return PokerHand.FOUR_OF_A_KIND;
if (rankCountCounts[3] == 1 && rankCountCounts[2] == 1)
    return PokerHand.FULL_HOUSE;
if (hasFlush)
    return PokerHand.FLUSH;
if (hasStraight)
    return PokerHand.STRAIGHT;
if (maxOfAKind == 3)
    return PokerHand.THREE_OF_A_KIND;
if (rankCountCounts[2] == 2)
    return PokerHand.TWO_PAIR;
if (rankCountCounts[2] == 1)
    return PokerHand.ONE_PAIR;
return PokerHand.HIGH_CARD;
```

So, how do I do this in a way that doesn't require looping over `<remaining>! / <remaining - blank spaces>` possibilities?

I'm assuming that there's a way to do this with combinatorics, but I don't know how to deal with the dependent possibilities given that the number of cards remaining may change and some cards are potentially fixed.

Comment: Is this a statistics/ probability question, or more of a programming question?

Comment: I was going to post it on stackoverflow, but their `statistics` tag says to consider posting your question here instead, and it's an algorithm question not really a programming question.

Comment: Exactly how is order important?  That has no relevance for the value of a poker hand.  Do you need the counts exactly or would approximations be acceptable?  Even if order is important, there are at most 50*49*48 =117600 possible ways to fill in those blanks in your example (and at most 5997600 in the worst case with one card already showing: the case with no cards showing has long been worked out and is available on just about any poker site or book).  This number is quite manageably small.

Comment: It's a variant where they must be in order for runs. Exact. And I'm doing a lot of these (read, ~millions) so running through 6 million combinations every time is a little absurd.

Answer (score 1):

> I want to get the counts of each possible outcome (high card, one pair, two pair, ... etc) if the blanks are filled with cards randomly.
>
> How do I do this in a way that doesn't require looping over `<remaining>! / <remaining - blank spaces>` possibilities?

The way most such card counters work is to randomly fill in the blanks as many times as you have the computational power and patience for. As you say, there are ~312 million actual options, but you might take a random sample of ~30 million and extrapolate.

Alternatively, if you really want the exact numbers, the only ways I can think of to reduce your calculations are to:

1. Be able to determine when a blank cannot further impact the hand
   type. For exactly a 5-card hand this is minimal, but if you are
   taking the best 5-card hand from 7 cards like in Hold'em, this could
   be leveraged quite a bit.
2. Use probability that the remaining card(s) increase the value of the
   hand. For example, with [4h, 4c, 4d, 2s, <blank>] the only cards
   that make a difference are 4s, 2h, 2d, 2c. Any other card is going
   to give you 3-of-a-kind regardless, so you really don't need to
   iterate through all the options at this point. This is really the same as point 1, just taken a step further.

Comment: Unfortunately, poker hands being poker hands, this severely under or over-represents certain hands. For instance, if you have the entire deck minus three of the four aces, you can make a royal flush in exactly one way. But this method will alternate between 0 and 10 (!) possibilities. I wonder if I could use a hybrid between Monte Carlo and "enumerate all scoring possibilities and calculate number of ways to draw said hand from the deck" for the rare hands. Hmm.